# Making part of text in Material Tooltip bold

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material

So, let's say I have a `mat-tooltip` element like this:

```html
<button mat-raised-button matTooltip="Info about the action">
  Action
</button>
```

Now, how to make only the **"Info"** part of text bold? I was thinking about using `:before` pseudo element, but the tooltip content in my case is **rendered dynamically.** Do you have any ideas on how to achieve it?

Comment: It's not possible. This is contrary to the [material design spec](https://material.io/design/components/tooltips.html#implementation): _Tooltips don’t display rich information including images and formatted text_ . Checkout this [feature request](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/5440#issuecomment-313740211)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the text can be bold, because mat-tooltip can be styled as well as its text font-size and color.

Comment: You can make the text bold by applying a `tooltipClass` to it. But making parts of the text bold can't be done this way

Comment: as suggested above mattooltip dont allow html so you can use the alternative tooltip. find the link https://www.freakyjolly.com/angular-8-add-hover-text-tooltip-module-without-any-dependency-in-angular-web-application/

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following in your `.component.css` file:

```css
::ng-deep .mat-tooltip {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```