# How to emphasize strings that are dynamic in Typescript

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am trying to emphasize a particular part of a text in Angular but only the dynamic part of the string. I have tried adding html elements in various places but that did not help. I am hoping I do not need to create a whole other component just to get the text make it bold an push it down to the other component that actually reads it.

In the HTML file:

```
<button mat-icon-button (click)="openThatThing()" matTooltip="Do the thing">
      <mat-icon>some-icon</mat-icon>
</button>
```

In the TS file:

```
openThatThing(): void {

this.action = thing.that.needs.done;
const messageBody = "Do this to \"" + this.current.name + "\"?";
const thisThing = this.dialog.open(ActionDialogComponent, {
  width: '400px',
  disableClose: true,
  hasBackdrop: false,
  panelClass: ["something", "mat-typography"],
  data: {title: "Confirm Thing", msgBody: messageBody, primaryAction: "Action"}
});
```

}

I would like `this.current.name` to be bold. I can't seem to find documentation or other stackoverflow articles on this particular matter. It is possible that I am not asking the question properly in the search engines.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Making part of text in Material Tooltip bold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51944603/making-part-of-text-in-material-tooltip-bold)

Comment: Looks promising. I will give it a look tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you for your response @Jacopo Sciampi, I do not think I am able to use your suggestion. The button located in the HTML file only calls the function `openThatThing`. The string I wish to emphasize is in the TS file, within the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I focused on the `ActionDialogueComponent` and from there I realized I could split out `this.current.name` from the string. Manipulate it however I wanted and stick it all back together in the aforementioned component's HTML file.

Answer (score 1):

You can style your text with HTML, for that you need to inject your HTML in ActionDialogComponent:

```html
<p [innerHtml]="data.msgBody"></p>
```

when you pass your msgBody you need to sanitize the HTML for security reasons:

```js
constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

openThatThing(): void {
    const messageBody = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml("Do this to <b>"+ this.current.name +"</b>?");
   // rest of the code
}
```

if you know what `this.current.name` can be, you can trust the HTML with no problem.

Comment: The problem I am having with this solution is that all there is in the HTML document is the function call used by the button. I do not have the option to use the "[property]=binding" as I understand it.

Comment: maybe you have to explain better your situation. As I understand, you want to open `ActionDialogComponent` in a MatDialog. Inside of `ActionDialogComponent` you want to display some text of `msgBody` in bold.  In this case you have to edit `ActionDialogComponent` as in my example, for example with `<p [innerHtml]="data.msgBody"></p>`

Comment: What I added to the original post is all the code used to display the string. As you can see there is no HTML tag or option to add one.

Comment: but you don't show the `ActionDialogueComponent` HTML in your question. You had to do some changes there. But I am happy you found a solution that fits you

Comment: I realize that was unfair to expect the solution the way I had formulated the question. I am very new to Angular and am deep diving in documentation and educational material to get better. I did learn something from the responses so it isn't a total loss. Thank you!